# Getting 404 error when accessing REST endpoint from Zuul API Gateway

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, microservices, netflix-zuul

Can anybody help me, I am twisting my mind already for these for 3 days now but can't make it to work.

API Gateway Application and Security Config and Resource Server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Application {

    /**
     * This is where the application is bootstrapped.
     *
     * @param arguments the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String... arguments) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, arguments);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
@Order(6)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .headers().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()            
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/xuath/login**", "/security/oauth/**", "/user/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/api/account**", "/user/api/account/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/xuath/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/admin/**").authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

Sample yml zuul routes:

```
zuul:
    routes:
        app-security:
            path: /security/**            
            retryable: true
            sensitive-headers:
            strip-prefix: false
```

Here is the app-security application and security config and resource server config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Application {

    /**
     * This is used for method level validation.
     *
     * @return the {@link MethodValidationPostProcessor}
     */
    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }

    /**
     * This is where the application is bootstrapped.
     *
     * @param arguments the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String... arguments) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, arguments);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

When I try to request from the browser after successful authentication the following url localhost:80/security/oauth/me it will return the json response of the currently logged user. But when I tried to use it in my AngularJS app using `$http.get()` it return 404 not found. Why?

Below is my AngularJS Controller:

```
duyogApp.controller 'loginCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) ->

    $http.get('http://localhost:80/security/oauth/me').then (d) ->
            console.log d.data
]
```

Comment: If you enable developer tools on your browser you can see the url used by angular http get. Can you confirm it is using the correct url?

Comment: @jay, yes it's the same url http://localhost:80/security/oauth/me

Comment: Could you post your angularjs code? and tag it as well?